# Girl who travels to creepy cartoon world

Tags: story-identification, cartoon

My husband told me about a movie he saw years ago, but he can't remember the name of it.

It's about a girl who travels to a world of cartoons and it's kind of creepy. It starts like a live action film, but then the girl travels to a cartoon dimension. I suggested *Alice in Wonderland*, but he said no.

Does anyone know what movie it is?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Films_with_live_action_and_animation

Comment: Sorry, but this could be almost anything. Can you ask him to run through the checklist [here](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) to see if there's any info he can add?

Comment: On the off chance, is it the segment with the kid from the Twilight Zone movie? His sister gets zapped into an animated world where she died.

Comment: @Broklynite - Cartoon hell; https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T5pQfOMkhmQ

Comment: @Valorum yup that's the one.

Comment: I've voted to reopen as it seems the question was answerable. @Cindy W, your original question was extremely broad, if you come back to the site in future, it's well worth running a few checks such as those suggested in the comments and trying to narrow it down a bit. I also think your questions might be better received if you make them less chatty. We have a kind of strange culture on stackexchange, and generally chit chat is seen as getting in the way, rather than being friendly, so I edited your post down a bit, in the hope of making it more suited to the site :)

Comment: **I'm voting to leave closed**. Although the edits have tidied up the question, they haven't added much more information to go off. @CindyW can you please add timelines (when did your husband watch it? when does he think it was created - even roughly).

Comment: duplicate of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/175670/fantasy-movie-with-black-and-white-queens (which is newer but has an accepted answer and wasn't closed as too broad)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It might be [MirrorMask](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MirrorMask) (2005).

> *The film's story revolves around a young girl named Helena Campbell, who is sick of her family's career as circus performers. Helena's
>   mother is hospitalized after they have an argument, and Helena finds
>   herself trapped in a fantasy world shortly after.*

Comment: Yes it's mirror mask! Thank you so much 

Comment: *Mirrormask* also has the world's creepiest version of the old song, [*Close To You.*](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=UVyZXHEhlHE)